# Controlling java socket's connection

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I'm writing a client-server application, using java TCP sockets.

Client and server are connected by a socket.
Sometimes server has to write a reply message for the client on this socket.

But in that moment, client's socket could be closed, not using close() method, but closing client's application.
Can you tell me, how server can recognize this situation, and avoid writing his reply message on this socket?

Comment: I would simply catch the IOException that would be thrown in the server's code.

Comment: Exactly. Handle errors. Don't try to predict the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do reliably.  If you establish that a connection is open, by the time you get around to writing to it, it may have been closed.  The reliable solution is to attempt the write, and handle any errors that may result.

Note that if you do get an error indication, there is no saying how much data got to the remote peer.  If you perform two writes, and the second write gets an error indication, it is quite possible that the remote peer shut down before the first write but the local peer only noticed it during the second write.